# How do I "unbind" Ctrl+BackSpace in URxvt?

Tags: terminal, emacs, key-binding, urxvt

My URxvt is mapping the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Backspace</kbd> key combination to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>. This is extremely annoying when using GNU Emacs.

How do I change that behavior?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After searching some more for this solution, I've found out an alternate solution. I'm mapping **Ctrl+BackSpace** to some other key combination and then I'm mapping this new combination to the desired behavior in my GNU Emacs.

To achieve this, add this to **~/.Xdefaults** (or whatever your distro uses for this):

```
URxvt.keysym.C-BackSpace: \033[33~
```

I'll leave this question open until a proper alternative appears (one that makes **urxvt** simply ignore it).

**BONUS**

To map this new key binding into GNU Emacs, you can use the describe-key function (usually **C-h k**) and type **Ctrl+BackSpace** to find out how the editor is seeing this stuff. In my case, it was **"S-"**. To achieve the desired behavior, in my case, I added this to **~/.emacs**:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "S-<f9>") 'backward-kill-word)
```

Answer (score 1):

I simply managed to unbind it with

`URxvt.keysym.C-BackSpace: command:\000`

Remember to do `xrdb ~/.Xresources` and restart urxvt.